# Google Dialogflow es - I get few intents repeated twice- happens where i have dynamic values

Tags: dialogflow-es

Google Dialogflow es - I am working on a sample to achieve

```
>Voice call to IVR number  
>prompt the caller about the language choice
>Customer presses language selection  
>IVR ask for the serial number of the device in the selected language  
>IVR to repeat the serial number
>customer will express the issue in local language 
>IVR to repeat the issue again 
>customer confirms  disconnect the call.
```

But here serial number intent and issue intent are repeating twice? can someone help me to fix this?

I have tried to read step by step instruction from few sample, But didnt work.

Have set all input context and output context as browsed on internet

I have exported this as a zip for reference
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KAWTsPfBNM1bCgENCJy-ODxut3jcMuHn?usp=sharing